# How to get a Folder icon with a preview?

Tags: c, winapi, icons

I wanted to get a folder icon to look like this

[image: like this]

But I actually got it to look like this

[image: like this].

My implementation：

```
HICON GetSystemIcon(IShellFolder* folder, PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE idpl) {
  IExtractIcon* extract_icon;
  folder->GetUIObjectOf(NULL, 1, &idpl, IID_IExtractIcon, NULL, (void**)&extract_icon);
  wchar_t icon_file[MAX_PATH] = {0};
  int icon_index = 0;
  UINT flag = GIL_SIMULATEDOC;
  extract_icon->GetIconLocation(GIL_FORSHELL, icon_file, MAX_PATH, &icon_index, &flag);
  HICON small_icon = NULL;
  HICON large_icon = NULL;
  UINT size = MAKELONG(32, 32);
  extract_icon->Extract(icon_file, icon_index, &large_icon, &small_icon, size);
}
```

How should I change it?

Comment: You are only extracting icons. You want to set the icon. Look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-create-icon-handlers

Comment: The interface you want is [IShellItemImageFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ishellitemimagefactory).

Comment: GIL_SIMULATEDOC is for files, not folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an official sample for this purpose you can use or refer to: "[Image Factory API Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/1d363ff4bd17d8e20415b92e2ee989d615cc0d91/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/shell/appplatform/UsingImageFactory)". It demonstrates how to use the IShellItemImageFactory interface to get the best possible image for an item.

And make sure your folder looks exactly what you expected in File explorer.

This is my target folder:

[image]

This is what I get using the sample:

[image]

The core related code lines:

```
        HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // Getting the IShellItemImageFactory interface pointer for the file.
            IShellItemImageFactory *pImageFactory;
            hr = SHCreateItemFromParsingName(argv[2], NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pImageFactory));
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                SIZE size = { nSize, nSize };

                //sz - Size of the image, SIIGBF_BIGGERSIZEOK - GetImage will stretch down the bitmap (preserving aspect ratio)
                HBITMAP hbmp;
                hr = pImageFactory->GetImage(size, SIIGBF_BIGGERSIZEOK, &hbmp);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    DialogBoxParamW(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDD_DIALOG1), NULL, DialogProc, (LPARAM)hbmp);
                    DeleteObject(hbmp);
                }
                else
                {
                    pwszError = L"IShellItemImageFactory::GetImage failed with error code %x";
                }

                pImageFactory->Release();
            }
            else
            {
                pwszError = L"SHCreateItemFromParsingName failed with error %x";
            }

            CoUninitialize();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks，I think this should be the effect I want.